# AWS API gateway configuration for a TCP socket server

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets

I want to host a simple TCP based socket server on AWS listening on port 3333. The only catch is that it should sit behind the AWS API gateway as the security policy does not allow exposing a public IP from an EC2 instance. Is this possible to achieve using API gateway. If yes, what are the configuration options I should be looking at

Comment: API gateway is for http. You may consider using network load balancer or classic one with tcp listeners.

Comment: Our security policy does not allow exposing a NLB/LB or EC2 with public IP to outside world. All incoming traffic is through API gateway. Do you mean its not possible in this scenario?